# Options to manage a Win7 machine remotely from macOS/Linux

Tags: linux, windows-7, macos, remote-access, remote-control

My mom lives on another continent and is very computer-illiterate, e.g. she doesn't know how to open Skype again after she mistakenly closed it so we can't talk to her for weeks (until somebody comes to her house and opens it again).

I will be visiting her next month, so I will have physical access to her machine and will be able to install anything I want. What are my options in 2019? Is VNC still the right tool for the job? Is there a more suitable tool I could first setup in a Win7 VM here and deploy as a startup item when I visit her?

I'm not a Windows user myself, so the tool to connect to and manage the remote host should run on macOS and Linux.

Comment: VNC would probably be fine for this.

Comment: Teamviewer is likely your best bet here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tier available for [RemotePC](https://www.remotepc.com/pricing.htm), you can access the remote computer from your browser.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my use case and it's very simple.